# Problem with pst-optic: Only the half picture is drawn

Tags: xetex, pst-optic

I just tried to complile the following picture with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-optic}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\newpsstyle{opticalAxis}{linewidth=0.5pt,linecolor=blue,linestyle=dashed}
\begin{pspicture}(-20,-6)(20,6)
\psgrid[style=gridstyle,subgriddiv=1,subgridcolor=gray!50] 
\rput(0,0){\lens[AB=5,focus=5,OA=-17,xLeft=-20,xRight=20,yTop=6,yBottom=-6,lensHeight=11]} 
\end{pspicture}


\end{document}
```

However the output looks like this:

[image: output]

Any idea what's wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: I compile with the workflow  latex, dvi->ps, ps->pdf, view pdf and I get the complete picture.  I'm using MikTex 2.9 with Windows 8.1

Comment: I can run it with `pdflatex` (option `pdf` for the document class, and the `enable-write18` switch for pdflatex), under MiKTeX 2.9, Windows7. But I do have the problem with `xelatex`.

Comment: I have no problem with `xelatex`. Up-to-date TL2014

Comment: @Bernard I tried it with pdflatex as suggested and it works, thanks! I didn't know the pdf switch for standalone but cannot find it documented in the manual. Do you have a reference for it's documentation?

Comment: I am using: XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)

Comment: run `texdoc pst-news10` for the optional argument `pdf`

Comment: @student: I have `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015)`

Comment: The optional `pdf` is handed by the document class to `pstricks`, which the knows it has to load `auto-pst-pdf`. The latter creates temporary  `.eps` images, crops them and converts to `.pdf` with the help of `ghostscript` and finally reincorporates them into the .pdf file.

Comment: @Herbert I shoud probably ugrade :-). I tried it on my other box with  Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014)  but the resulting picture only contains the labels.

Comment: @student: The labels are set on TeX-Level. I suppose a problem with your xetex definition file which uses wrong paper sizes. What happens if you use article class instead of standalone?

Comment: With article it works, even in the old version (2013).

Answer (score 1):

It works with an up-to-date TeXLive 2015:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optic}
\begin{document}

\newpsstyle{opticalAxis}{linewidth=0.5pt,linecolor=blue,linestyle=dashed}
\begin{pspicture}(-20,-6)(20,6)
\psgrid[style=gridstyle,subgriddiv=1,subgridcolor=gray!50] 
\rput(0,0){\lens[AB=5,focus=5,OA=-17,xLeft=-20,xRight=20,yTop=6,yBottom=-6,lensHeight=11]}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]